# Hide button after last class has been shown

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following,

```
$("#slider1next").click(function () {
        $(".text:visible").next().show();
    });
```

When the last class (.text) has been shown i want to hide #slider1next how would i go about this?

http://jsfiddle.net/ma9ic/U2UZ4/3/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a callback function to the `show()` function, and evaluate the index:

```
$("#slider1next").click(function () {
    $(".text:visible").next().show(function() {  
        if($(this).index() == $('.text').length)
        {
            $('#slider1next').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

See the [**updated jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/U2UZ4/4/).

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$("#slider1next").click(function () {
    var $next = $('.text:visible:last').next();
    $next.length ? $next.show() : $(this).hide();
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/U2UZ4/13/)

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#slider1next").click(function () {
$(".text:visible").next().show();
if ($('.text:last').is(':visible')){
    $('#slider1next').hide();
}
});
```

check if the last element is visible and hide the button.
http://jsfiddle.net/U2UZ4/12/

Answer (score 1):

You can check whether visible length is equivalent to all text length.

http://jsfiddle.net/U2UZ4/6/

```
$("#slider1next").click(function () {
    if ($(".text:visible").length == $(".text").length) { $(this).hide(); }
    $(".text:visible").next().show();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to verify is there's a next div after the last show one, like that

```
$("#slider1next").click(function () {
    var next = $(".text:visible:last").next();
    console.log(next);
    if (next.length > 0) {
        next.show();
    } else {
        $(this).hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to check if `fourth_one` is visible or not, if visible hide `slider1next`

```
    $("#slider1next").click(function () {
    $(".text:visible").next().show();
    if($('#fourth_one').is(':visible'))
    {
        $('#slider1next').hide();
    }
});
```

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cpru6/1/)

Comment: If we add another item (for example `#fifth_one`), we have to update the jQuery selector here.

Comment: @BenM ahh did not notice that he used an ID and not a class. Good point.